# How to Connect Cowboy (Erlang) websocket to webflow.io generated webpage

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy, webflow

I’m want to use cowboy websocket Interface to interact with a webpage generated with webflow. I would like to have an simple example how to add javascript implementing websocket connected to webflow HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

2. Drag a `Container`, which is a `div`, onto your page. Give it the ID `server_info`.
3. Drag a `Button` onto your page.  Give it the ID `get_server_info`.
4. The `Page Settings` allow you to [add javascript to a page](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/custom-code-in-the-head-and-body-tags#before-%3C-/-body-%3E-tag). The [js for connecting to a server with a websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) will look something like this:

   ```
      <script>
       var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/please_upgrade_to_websocket");

       ws.onerror = function(event) {
           console.error("[ME]WebSocket error observed:", event);
       };
       ws.onclose = function(event) {
           console.log("[ME]WebSocket is closed now.");
       };

       $("#get_server_info").click(function() {
           if(ws.readyState == 1) {               
               ws.send("My data");
           }
           else {
               alert("Websocket not open! readyState: " + ws.readyState);
          }
       });

       ws.onmessage = function (event) {
           alert("Data was retrieved from server and will be inserted in page.");
           $("#server_info").text(event.data);

       };

      </script>
   ```
5. [Create a new cowboy app](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.5/guide/getting_started/) called `hello_erlang`.
6. Create some routes and and specify their handler functions by putting the following in `hello_erlang/src/hello_erlang_app.erl`:

   ```
    -module(hello_erlang_app).
    -behaviour(application).

    -export([start/2]).
    -export([stop/1]).

    start(_Type, _Args) ->
        HelloRoute = { "/", hello_handler, [] },
        WebSocketRoute = {"/please_upgrade_to_websocket", myws_handler, []},
        CatchallRoute = {"/[...]", no_matching_route_handler, []},

        Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
            {'_', [HelloRoute, WebSocketRoute, CatchallRoute]}
        ]),


        {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
            [{port, 8080}],
            #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch} }
        ),

        hello_erlang_sup:start_link().

    stop(_State) ->
        ok.
   ```
7. To serve the simple html page with the button, I used `hello_erlang/src/hello_handler.erl`:

   ```
    -module(hello_handler).
    -behavior(cowboy_handler).

    -export([init/2]).

    init(Req0, State) ->
        io:format("[ME]Entered hello_handler~n"),
        Body = my_get_file("html/form.htm"),  %% Body can be a binary() or an iolist() (which is a list containing integers, strings, or binaries)
        Req = cowboy_req:reply(200,
            #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/html">>},
            Body,
            Req0),

        {ok, Req, State}.

    my_get_file(Path) ->
        PrivDir = code:priv_dir(hello_erlang),  %% Finds the path of an application's priv directory
        AbsPath = filename:join([PrivDir, Path]),

        case file:read_file(AbsPath) of 
            {ok, Bin} -> Bin;
            _  -> ["<div>Cannot read file: ", Path, "</div>"]  %% iolist()
        end.
   ```

According to the [erlang docs](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#directory-structure), the `priv` directory is where application specific files should go.  Below is the `form.htm` page, which I put it in the directory `hello_erlang/priv/html/` (I created the `html` directory).  In the `<head>` section of the html page there is a `<script>` tag which links to the `jquery` library, which is used by the javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"   
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="server_info">Server info</div>
    <button type="button" id="get_server_info">Get sever info</button>

    <script>
     var my_websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/please_upgrade_to_websocket");

     my_websocket.onerror = function(event) {
         console.error("[ME]WebSocket error observed:", event);
     };
     my_websocket.onclose = function(event) {
         console.log("[ME]WebSocket is closed now.");
     };

     $("#get_server_info").click(function() {
         if(my_websocket.readyState == 1) {               
             my_websocket.send("My data");
         }
         else {
             alert("Websocket not open! readyState: " + my_websocket.readyState );
        }
     });

     my_websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
         $("#server_info").text(event.data);
         alert("Data was retrieved from server and will be inserted in page.");
     };

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Another way to serve the html file is to do away with `hello_handler.erl` and set the route like this:

```
HelloRoute = { "/", cowboy_static, {priv_file, hello_erlang, "html/form.htm"} },
```

You would put `form.htm` in the directory `hello_erlang/priv/html/` (I created the html directory).  See the cowboy docs on [static files](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.8/guide/static_files/).   When you don't need to use erlang to alter the html file in some way before sending it to the client, that is the simplest way to serve the file.

8. `hello_erlang/src/myws_handler.erl`:

   ```
    -module(myws_handler).
    -export([init/2, websocket_init/1, websocket_handle/2, websocket_info/2]).


    init(Req, State) ->
        {cowboy_websocket, Req, State}.  %Perform websocket setup

    websocket_init(State) ->
        io:format("[ME]: Inside websocket_init()~n"),
        {ok, State}.

    websocket_handle({text, Msg}, State) ->
        {Hours, Minutes, Secs} = time(),

        {
             reply, 
             {text, io_lib:format("[~w:~w:~w]: Server received: ~s", [Hours, Minutes, Secs, Msg]) },
             State
        };
    websocket_handle(_Other, State) ->  %Ignore
        {ok, State}.


    websocket_info({text, Text}, State) ->
        {reply, {text, Text}, State};
    websocket_info(_Other, State) ->
        {ok, State}.
   ```
9. `hello_erlang/src/no_matching_route_handler.erl`:

   ```
    -module(no_matching_route_handler).
    -behavior(cowboy_handler).

    -export([init/2]).

    init(Req0, State) -> %State comes from last argument of route
        Req = cowboy_req:reply(404,
            #{<<"content-type">> => <<"text/plain">>},
            <<"[ME] 404. Whoops! (No matching route!)">>,
            Req0),
        {ok, Req, State}.
   ```

---

Then, in the top level directory of your app, `hello_erlang` in this case, start your cowboy server:

```
...cowboy_apps/hello_erlang$ make run
```

Then, enter the following url in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

That will cause cowboy to serve up the html page containing the button.  Clicking on the button will send some data to the server using the websocket, and the server will respond, then the js will insert the response in the web page.

`Webflow` is really irrelevant to the answer: it doesn't matter how or what you use to create html and javascript, the end product is an html page, which you put somewhere in your server's directory.  When a browser requests the html file from your server, the server sends the html file to the browser,  then the browser reads the file and produces the pretty text and pictures you see, and the browser executes the javascript at the appropriate time.  A browser has no idea who are what created the html and javascript in the file.