# How to make erlang application?

Tags: intellij-idea, websocket, server, erlang

i'm trying to build the [example](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/erlang_websocket_server_cowboy_tutorial.html) to run an erlang websocket server.
I created all that files and put them into one folder, add the rebar file and ran

```
./rebar get-deps
```

inside the folder direction.
But there is no

```
make
make runconsole
```

and nothing's happening.

Is there also a possibility to create that websocket server using IntelliJ? I tried to put that 3 .erl files into IntelliJ and want to Build the project but I receive

```
erlc: 2: Warning: behaviour cowboy_http_handler undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

The `make` command reads something called a Makefile, which is a file written in a certain format, which tells the `make` command what it is supposed to do, e.g. compile some files with the listed names using the listed commands. Because there is no Makefile listed in that tutorial, you should have gotten an error something like this:

> No targets specified and no makefile found.

You can contact the author of the tutorial at his github account and ask him where the Makefile is. Actually, the Makefile for the tutorial is here:

https://github.com/marcelog/erws

> I created all that files and put them into one folder

The instructions in the Makefile depend on the exact directory structure that the author has here:

https://github.com/marcelog/erws

I tried using `rebar3` and changing some stuff in the Makefile, but I still got errors.  The problem is that `rel` directory: I don't know how to create all the stuff in there.  You need to use `rebar`  and `reltool` for that:

https://gist.github.com/FabioBatSilva/f1d1c4ea250302fed8c2

Here is a cowboy websockets example that I came up with last year, see if it helps:

[How to Connect Cowboy (Erlang) websocket to webflow.io generated webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682534/how-to-connect-cowboy-erlang-websocket-to-webflow-io-generated-webpage)

It uses the Erlang.mk build system as described in the cowboy docs here:

https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.5/guide/getting_started/